# New standalone ESXi 5 deployments - USB versus SD card?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, usb-flash-drive

Now that the old full VMWare ESX with service console is no longer, I'm redeploying some standalone ESXi servers. I'm using HP ProLiant ML and DL G6 and G7 servers. Does it make more sense to utilize the internal USB port for ESXi or the internal SD card slot? I'm using the HP ESXi 5 build, but am not sure what the recommended practice is. Any recommendations on cards/USB drives for this purpose?

BTW - these will be all-in-one storage servers with the onboard disk storage presented via PCIe passthrough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is whichever medium hp supplied the build on.  I believe that they generally supply USB unless you ask for SD.

Comment: I don't have HP-supplied media. I'm installing onto cards from the HP ISO image.

Comment: As Jim suggests it really doesn't matter a bit, I have a number of spare HP-supplied SD cards in my office drawer by the way, if you let me know how many you want I should be able to send you them.

Comment: You should use oem media, its a little more rigorously tested than consumer cards/sticks

Comment: Excellent advice. Chopper3, I may be interested in those cards!